# Can we take conditional expectations on a random variable that has been fixed to a value, such as $E( E\left( Y \mid X,Z=1 \right) \mid X)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose we are trying to estimate a random variable $Y$ by conditioning on three random variables, $X,Z$, with the condition that $Z \in \{0,1\}$ is discrete. I am interested in the conditional expectation of $Y$ conditioned on $X$. However, suppose I **only** have the expectation of $Y$ on $X$ with $Z$ set to be $1$:

$$
E(Y\mid X, Z=1)
$$

By law of iterated expectations, I believe I can have the following form:

\begin{align*}
    E\bigg( E\left( Y \mid X,Z=1 \right) \mid X\bigg)
    &= E[Y \mid X]
\end{align*}

In the above, it is valid to take the conditional expectation of $E(Y\mid X, Z=1)$? I am hesitant about this result as I have conditioned on a random variable ($Z$) that has been fixed to a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the general definition of conditional expectations given sigma algebras we can write $E(Y|X,Z=1)$ as $E(Y|\sigma (X, I_{Z=1})$. Hence the law of iterated conditioning applies and the formula you have stated is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense. If it were the case that $Y,X,Z$ are all discrete, would writing it in terms of the sigma algebra still be a valid representation? Thank you.